# How can I connect multiple sound devices to OBS?

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, video-streaming, obs-studio

I have an atypical audio setup that I am trying to get to work reasonably for streaming with Open Broadcaster Software (OBS).

My ideal situation is that I could see each of the inputs from my USB audio interface (Focusrite 18i8) as separate inputs in OBS, and that I have separate game audio in OBS as well.

I know that *some* of this is available via the use of [virtual audio cables](http://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/index.htm), however, that seems limited to creating one or two audition audio inputs (and the USB audio interface has 4 XLR hardware inputs alone).

How can I connect all these different sound devices to work in OBS?

Comment: I'd like to route the hardware inputs through adobe audition if possible (to add gain, etc.) but I didn't want to complicate things any more than necessary.